# how to add encodingStyle to soap client using c#

Tags: c#, soap, envelope

the data I send to a web service, gets there with some strange characters.
so the web service developer asked me to add this code to the soap envelope:

```
 soap:encodingStyle=http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding
```

I tried adding this code, but it did not work:

```
 MessageHeader aMessageHeader = 
MessageHeader.CreateHeader("encodingStyle", "http://tempuri.org", 
"2003/05/soap-encoding");                  
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(aMessageHeader);
```

how do i add to the soap:envelope  a encodingStyle attribute  in c#?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you reported. I found that this was a reported issue in the WCF.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3870

For the fix, I updated the following NuGet packages in my project from version "4.4.*" to "4.7.0"

- System.ServiceModel.Duplex
- System.ServiceModel.Http
- System.ServiceModel.NetTcp
- System.ServiceModel.Security

It now includes the "encodingStyle" attribute in the correct location.